# Draw a line in Visio between objects without obscuring the text in the label

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have two vertically arranged shapes connected by a line with a text label on the line. I don't want the line to run *through* the text label because it obscures the text. What I have done to get around this is to disconnect the line from the top shape and draw it from some point in space just below the text area. This is a pain and has to be readjusted every time I move shapes. I was hoping to find a way to connect the line to the text label directly or possibly apply a fill to the text label area to make it look like the line starts below the text field. Any suggestions?

I tried to illustrate this below. Assume the boxes are actually shapes. You can (hopefully) see that the line goes between shapes runs straight through the text label.

```
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
+---------+
     |
     |
Text |label
     |
     |
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
+---------+
```

Ideally it would look something like the below after the "fix"

```
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
+---------+
     |
     |
Text label
     |
     |
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the shape, then right-click -> **Format** -> **Text**, select **Text Block**, set **Text Background** to **Solid Color** and select white.

Comment: I looked for this but couldn't find it. In 2013 I have no Format option in the right-click menu but having remembered doing this before I searched again and finally found it. There's probably a better way but I selected the shape, open Paragraph options > Text Block tab > Text background. I have a colored background so I chose a matching color instead of white but I still have the problem where the line shows above the text label, is hidden behind the text label, and then extends to the shape. So... this is progress but I don't want the line showing above the text label.

Comment: Well, in that case put your text in a text box rather than the shape itself, put the text box below the shape, group them. Now you can glue your connector to the text block shape.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because it's the easiest and closest to what I wanted. Hopefully in the future they will add the ability to connect to the textlabel without having to edit the Shapesheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't quite match **Visio 2021**. I'd have just commented but I wanted better formatting so, here's an updated answer.

1. Select the shape and right-click, `Edit Text`.
2. Right click within the resulting selected text and select `Paragraph`.
3. In the resulting `Text` dialog, select the `Text Block` tab.
4. Within tab's `Text Background` section, select `Solid color`:

   - Use the color dropdown to change the color to your desired background color, e.g. `White, White`.
5. You may also need to select the connector line and `Send to Back`, `Send backward`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: open the shape's shapesheet, insert section Connection points, create a new connection point and set the point's X and Y coords to the TxtPinX and TxtPinY. Glue to that.

Comment: I didn't know the Shapesheet existed. Thanks for sharing this... I may use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape and press Bring to Front under the Arrange section of the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

Success.  This is why I hate to use Visio, but it has good results-final product (**if you are willing to spend a lot of time**).  I had the same problem, and didn't want to be defeated by drawing a text box next to the connector.

I solved it as follows:
Select the problem connector.
While its selected, go to the Home/Font group and click pull down arror for that group (bottom right corner of box).
Click the tab that saysText Block and select  Solid Color, and then apply a White backround, **THEN APPLY**, then OK.

Why couldn't they just put it in the right click when selected?

Comment: This site works differently, it is not a discussion forum.  Please edit your question and remove all the rant, or it may get deleted.